# refactor model method multiple mount_uploader for carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, refactoring, carrierwave

I have Rails (4) app and I'm using carrierwave to upload an image to an S3 bucket in production (and local in dev). It's all working, but I wanted to refactor my code.

**My model:**

```
class Blogging < ActiveRecord::Base

mount_uploader :picture1, Picture1Uploader  
mount_uploader :picture2, Picture1Uploader  
mount_uploader :picture3, Picture1Uploader    
mount_uploader :picture4, Picture1Uploader  
mount_uploader :picture5, Picture1Uploader  
mount_uploader :picture6, Picture1Uploader  
mount_uploader :picture7, Picture1Uploader  
mount_uploader :picture8, Picture1Uploader  
mount_uploader :picture9, Picture1Uploader  
mount_uploader :picture10, Picture1Uploader  
mount_uploader :picture11, Picture1Uploader  
validate :picture_size  


private
  def picture_size
    if picture1.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture1, "should be less than 5 MB")
    end
  end


end
```

**After some refactoring, I have this:**

```
class Blogging < ActiveRecord::Base


for i in 1..11 
 mount_uploader :"picture#{i}", Picture1Uploader
end


validate :picture_size
validates :picture1, :news_title, :news_body, presence: true 



private

 def picture_size
    pics = Array.new(11) {|i| "picture#{i+1}"} 
        pics.each do |p|
        if p.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture1, "should be less than 5 MB")
        end
     end
 end
end
```

The `mount_uploader`, while ugly work fine. But I can't find a way to make `picture_size` limit the size of each picture (from 1 to 11).

- I can make it work using 11 times a different method or with a case operator. But i am trying to refactor.
- I'd love to put my "for" loop in a method and call it but can't figure out how. if i define a method and call it all the image vanish and no file get uploaded (locally or on the S3 bucket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def picture_size
  pics = Array.new(11) {|i| "picture#{i+1}"}.each do |pic_name|
    p = self.send pic_name
    if p.size > 5.megabytes
      self.errors.add(:picture1, "should be less than 5 MB")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it's working but not for the error message :


`def picture_size`
    `pics = Array.new(11) {|i| "picture#{i+1}"}.each do |pic_name| `
      `p = self.send pic_name `
      `if p.size > 5.megabytes`
         `errors.add(:picture1, "should be less than 5 MB")`
      `end`
    `end ` 
 `end`

with what i refactor :picture1 ?

Comment: Works i just replaced picture1 by : `self.errors.add(pic_name, "should be less than 5 MB")` Thanks